# CSS zoom not blurry but pixelated

Tags: css, zooming

I'd like to use zoom property in CSS for images but would not like to have a blurry effect to enlarged images but rather pixelated. How can I achieve this?

edit: if neccesary, it is ok to use other properties or other languages.

Comment: I would bet a fair sum of money that you can't, at least not in a cross-browser way, definitely not through the `zoom` property alone.

Comment: is there any other way to do it? maybe in other languages?

Comment: @user229044 [you can now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77383713/2518317), [CSS3 est 2015](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot (currently) use upscaling and specify that the browser should use nearest-neighbor zooming, neither with HTML images, upsized HTML5 canvases, using `drawImage()` on a canvas to draw the image larger, nor zooming up images on SVG.

Here's a solution *(written for [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875850/how-to-create-a-pixelized-svg-image-from-a-bitmap/4879849))* showing how to 'zoom' an image using nearest-neighbor pixelation by re-creating the image as rectangles in SVG:   http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_image_zoom_svg.xhtml

Here's another solution showing how to achieve this same effect using HTML5 Canvas (drawing rectangles on the canvas for the zoom):
http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_image_zoom.html

Answer (score 1):

[`image-rendering:pixelated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/01zwt6xv/)

Comment: Please don't post answers that contain only JSFiddle links, your code is required to go *in the answer*, not on an external code-hosting platform.

Comment: @user229044 All the code is literally in the answer, he simply needs to add `image-rendering:pixelated` to his css for the image, or, indeed, to the `<body>`. The demo is only needed because he gave no code in the question for me to augment. Further, documentation is linked if more explanation is required, it doesnt "contain only JSFiddle links"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a lightweight jQuery plugin called [Zoomoz](http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/). The settings include easing and native animation too.