# Resize image without blurriness

Tags: javascript, css, image, web-applications, minecraft

I am creating a web app for Minecraft, and I need to grab someones skin, and resize it without the blurriness. Maybe some javascript or something can help with this problem.

Comment: You cannot magically add detail to an image.

Comment: @SLaks Au contraire, that's the *only* way you can add detail to an image!

Comment: If you want to resize the image proportionally, you can set a fixed `width` and let `height` be `auto` and vice versa. e.g `<img src="image.png" width="300" height="auto">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe you want to resize images without interpolation and using nearest-neighbor only, e.g.:

[image: crisp Mario]

rather than:

[image: blurry Mario]

Unfortunately, there's no simple way to do this with CSS so you'll have to either:

1. Scale the images with nearest-neighbor on the server-side and serve them, or,
2. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597081/how-to-stretch-images-with-no-antialiasing/) for a convoluted answer involving HTML5 canvas.

Comment: There *is* a simple way to do this in CSS now. Take a look at the linked question.