# Disable antialising when scaling images

Tags: css, background-image, antialiasing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to stretch images with no antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597081/how-to-stretch-images-with-no-antialiasing)

Is it in any way possible to disable antialiasing when scaling up an image ?

Right now, i get something that looks like this :

[image: What i get]

Using the following css code :

```css
#bib {
    width: 104px;
    height: 104px;
    background-image: url(/media/buttonart_back.png);
    background-size: 1132px 1360px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

What I would like, is something like this :

[image: What i seek]

In short, any CSS flag to **disable** anti-aliasing from when scaling up images, preserving hard edges.

Any javascript hacks or similar are welcome too.

(Yes, I am aware that php and imagemagick can do this as well, but would prefer a css based solution.)

**UPDATE**
The following have been suggested :

```css
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
```

But that doesn't seem to work on background images.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Try this,
it's a fix for removing it in all browsers.

```
img { 
    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /* STOP SMOOTHING, GIVE ME SPEED  */
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox                        */
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera                          */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Chrome (and eventually Safari) */
    image-rendering: pixelated;                 /* Universal support since 2021   */
    image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         /* CSS3 Proposed                  */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE8+                           */

}
```

Sources:

http://nullsleep.tumblr.com/post/16417178705/how-to-disable-image-smoothing-in-modern-web-browsers

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/01/pixelated

GitaarLAB

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in Chrome.

Comment: Neither in Opera >=15

Comment: I see this working in Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit) on my iMac

Comment: Blast from the passsss....uh future `:)`: You might want to add the current CSS3 standard to the list: `image-rendering: pixelated`, see: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/01/pixelated

Comment: This doesn't work on background images on WebKit. Can't tell if it's a bug or not.

Comment: +1 Kasper Sebastian Brandt Jensen Can you please write the version numbers in the comments? As it has been five years now and perhaps some can be removed or are changed in the meanwhile?

Comment: @Kasper Sebastian Brandt Jensen, it appears that this does not work in Microsoft Edge, when things are scaled using the css property `transform: scale(2)`...

Comment: @lanewinfield Does the background repeat? Could be https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=177037.

Comment: working for me on Chrome 65 for a `<canvas />` element. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

CSS that works in **Firefox Only**:

```
img { image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; }
```

It worked for me (**firefox 16.0**)
[image]

Comment: Nice. But Im guessing other browsers dont have a similar key ?

Comment: no. atleast not known to me...:)