# png icons have jagged edges when sized with CSS

Tags: icons, png

I'm having trouble (pulling my hair out!) figuring out how to smooth the edges of my png icons. They are sized via CSS and are saved as PNG at 263px.

I've tried resaving as GIF's and also a variety of CSS hacks:
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Ideally I need a solution that smooths out the edges of the image (not the square borders) across all major browsers, as they all seem to be suffering and creating jaggy edges.

Thanks in advance

CSS:

`width: 20px;
height: 20px;`

Here's an image taken from my site:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use CSS to do this?  Try saving the images as the smaller size in the first place.  Your image editor should surely do a better job of smoothing the edges than a brower using CSS. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaggies

Comment: the images are all quite contrasty and require pin-sharp edges. If I can I'd like to see a CSS solution, as it's site-wide

Comment: "require pin-sharp edges" isn't this what you're trying to fix?

Comment: no. please read the question.

Comment: Your question states "Ideally I need a solution that smooths out the edges of the image" and now your comment says "the images require pin-sharp edges", which is it?  It sounds like you want the aliasing on the images to disappear http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing

Comment: spatial anti aliasing...that seems to be my problem! How do I apply Nearest-Neighbour anti-aliasing via CSS to the images above then?

Comment: See the links in my answer.  If these don't work, the fallback solution would be resizing them in your image editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these offer potential solutions to CSS image rendering options:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering
- [Disable antialising when scaling images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068103/disable-antialising-when-scaling-images)
- http://nullsleep.tumblr.com/post/16417178705/how-to-disable-image-smoothing-in-modern-web-browsers

Comment: Thanks - Seems like it's not an exact art then. The final solution was to resize the images, although I would have preferred a CSS only solution.

Answer (score -1):

## #logo {-webkit-transform: initial;}