# HTML Disable anti-aliasing on background-image

Tags: html, css

I've seen many methods for disabling anti aliasing for images, but how can I apply this to the "background-image"? I have divs with a background image, and the aliasing code isn't working with it. Can't somebody help?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @dreamhunter I have tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068103/disable-antialising-when-scaling-images doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `image-rendering: pixelated;` on the `Class` of your background image div?

If not, you can try this tutorial on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/)

Here is the summery. **All rights to original Authors**

```css
.pixelated {
      image-rendering: pixelated;
}

.resize {
  width: 45%;
  clear: none;
  float: left;
}
.resize:last-of-type {
  float: right;
}
.resize img {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="original">  
    <h1>Original image size</h1>   
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14179/qrcode.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="resize">  
  <h2>
    <code>image-rendering: auto;</code>
  </h2> 
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14179/qrcode.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="resize">  
  <h2>
    <code>-rendering: pixelated;</code>
  </h2> 
  <img class="pixelated" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14179/qrcode.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: I have already tried that, plus these methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068103/disable-antialising-when-scaling-images but it doesn't work on background-image images

Comment: try it on your `<div>` element. It worked for me.