# Disable tiled background smoothing in Safari

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to disable background smoothing in Safari?
I'm trying to make, for example, the tiled background like this:

```css
div#dashed
{
  width: 10rem;
  height: 7rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: url("https://tut.etogo.net/_files/diagonalbg.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="dashed">
```

So, the background is like that:
[image: Diagonal dashes]

And I expect the background to look like that (zoomed):
[image: Tiled background]

But in Safari it looks like that:
[image]
Zoomed: [image]

So, I see Safari does some antialiasing/smoothing on the edges - is there a way to disable it? I tried different "image-rendering" parameters but with no success. Tried that in IE, Edge, FF, Chrome and Opera - everything renders fine, but not in Safari. maybe there's some css for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable antialising when scaling images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068103/disable-antialising-when-scaling-images)

Comment: Looks like it's different problem. It works well in any browser except safari and nothing helps, including advices from that question

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your background was repeat.
You can try it

`background-size:cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Setting size for your background-image.

Comment: Sure, it is because of repeat. I cannot set “cover” because it will scale the image

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using an image, you can achieve the same effect with pure CSS.

```css
.gradient {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000, #fff 1px, #fff 15px);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

You might want to fiddle around to reach the desired outcome.

A bit more info, and tips can be found on https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

Comment: Sure, but just for that case. It’s just an example to illustrate problem, i am looking for the solution that would work with any image. At last it works in any browser except safari! )))

Comment: Strange thing is that `image-rendering: pixelated;` SHOULD work in Safari, in theory. I can't figure out yet why it doesn't work though...

Comment: Just checked it once more - does not work, no effect at all. Probably it's for images only, not for background images