# Image is pixelated in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to render a crisp sharp logo but it gets pixelated even tho the resolution is 10832x1492px (I tried diff resolutions (2k px, 500px) but the result is still pixelation)

I am using VueJS with PrimeVue

`<Image src="/logo.png" alt="logo" width="450" />`

`<Image src="/logo.png" alt="logo" />`

Any idea why it's getting pixelated?

[image]

Btw. it's created in Inkscape and being exported

[image]

It's not a duplicate of: [Disable antialising when scaling images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068103/disable-antialising-when-scaling-images) .. i want the exact oposity

Comment: If you mean the aliasing artifacts that are noticeable especially in letter A, I think they're already present in the original image. Rendering the image file with a browser is not going to improve quality.

Comment: how do I export it better? is it an Inkscape settings?

Comment: Are you sure the lines are not "pixelated" in the original image? If they are not, and the display size and the actual size of the image differ significantly then the rendering can have artifacs from up and down scaling. You can check if using different setting for [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) will solve the problem. But you should avoid a significant size difference.

Comment: `It's not a duplicate of: Disable antialising when scaling images .. i want the exact oposity`: did you try the usage of `image-rendering`? That property applies for both up and down-scaling. And artifacts can happen in both directions.

Comment: If it's created in *Inkscape*, it could be exported to SVG instead of PNG. This way, it might be smaller, especially if you optimize it with [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) and will certainly be **always rendered in a clean way**, for retina screens also.

Comment: awesome, will try @PatrickJanser

Comment: For the SVG, if you are using a font which is only available on your computer, you'll certainly have to **convert the text to a path**.  Better copy the text object with **CTRL** + **C** and paste it at the same place with **CTRL** + **ALT** + **V**, hide one of them (to keep it for future edits of the text) and then convert the other one to a path with **CTRL** + **ALT** + **C** or in the menu *Path* -> *Object to path*. Export it to plain SVG and pass it through [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) if necessary.

Comment: I think you may have antialiasing options somewhere in that dialogue.