# Upscaling canvas data as fast as possible

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have got a canvas and I display image using it via the `putImageData()` method after updating bytes in clamped array got by `getImageData.data`.

That works nicely, but I need to scale *2 in Y-direction.

Of course I can do it without a question here too by repeating every lines twice, but it requires too much time to render a frame then (I display 25 frames per second). I've read about the ability to scale image with `drawImage()` method. The only problem that as far as I know, using `drawImage()` is slower than using `putImageData()`, and it was required in old browser versions like Firefox/2 (or such).

How can I upscale the image in Y direction twice as fast as possible?

By the way, is it possible to get similar solution to gain full screen resolution somehow (a flash - not JS - example: like what youtube does when you go to fullscreen)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the whole canvas to scale, you can do this without any extra javascript. Just set a size in CSS that has twice the width and height specified in the canvas.

```
<canvas width="200" height="100" style="width:200; height: 200">
```

See the [W3 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width).

**Edit:**

Looking at the question linked by Alnitak below: If you want nearest-neighbor scaling rather than antialiasing you can do this:

```
canvas {
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}
```

Comment: but note that this will cause anti-aliasing.  That may be a good thing, or it may not...

Comment: Hmm. Is there any anti-aliasing, if I do scale exactly by *2? It can be a nice solution, but I don't know how much CPU time is consumed by the browser then to do it, since I am out of resources already quire heavily. It's good for me if it's still faster than doing it "by hand" in JS. But I will try and compare the result, thanks for your answer!

Comment: yes, even at exactly *2 it'll anti-alias - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8597422/6782

Comment: Thanks. I am curious (but it would be another question) if it can be done better (more control on the method, maybe faster) with WebGL or something similar though.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve vertical scaling (without anti-aliasing) by just grabbing one image *row* at a time with `getImageData` and then replicating that row multiple times with `putImageData`, e.g.:

```
var oy = 0;
for (var y = 0; y < sh; ++y) {
    var data = src_ctx.getImageData(0, y, sw, 1);
    for (var n = 0; n < scale; ++n) {
        dst_ctx.putImageData(data, 0, oy++);
    }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/hYZ3U/ for a worked example that completes in 3ms on my machine.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's time for me to do some test and benchmark which looks better and which is the faster :)

Comment: @LGB the CSS scaling method will almost certainly be faster, since it just offloads the work to the rendering system.  However the anti-aliasing it produces might well be undesirable.