# How to make css background-size scale linearly?

Tags: css, background, background-image

So when I scale a background image in CSS3, using the `background-size` property, like this:

```
.one {
    background-image: url(sprites/1.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

then it scales the picture: [image: Like this]

How can I make it so the picture is not blurred like that? Is it possible without a higher resolution image?

Comment: Yep, you need a higher resolution image.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the point. Do you want to scale up a picture above its resolution?

Comment: SVG FTW! (yeah, you've run out of resolution)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stretch images with no antialiasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597081/how-to-stretch-images-with-no-antialiasing)

Answer (score 1):

If the whole background image is purely just a black line, as shown, before you save the image, change it to an indexed image (instead of RGB), and give it an index of only two colours.  That way there will be no blur (antialiasing) and it will scale perfectly well.  It will also make your background image a very tiny file size, which helps for quick loading.  Save the indexed image either as png, or gif.

Comment: Don't know if this actually works or not, but it's a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use a image type like SVG which handles scale operations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics

> Though the SVG Specification primarily focuses on vector graphics markup language, its design includes the basic capabilities of a page description language like Adobe's PDF. It contains provisions for rich graphics, and is compatible with CSS for styling purposes. SVG has the information needed to place each glyph and image in a chosen location on a printed page