# How to avoid resampling when zooming imageOverlay in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm using [imageOverlay](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#imageoverlay) in Leaflet 1.0.0.

When zooming in, the image is resampled and becomes progressively "blurrier" the further you zoom in. (Leaflet is being helpful by interpolating pixel values as it zooms.)

I would like to avoid this resampling so that the image layer gets "blockier" as you zoom in. That is, it gives the impression to the user of the pixels being progressively enlarged as they zoom in.

I can see no way in the Leaflet API to control this. I can work around it somewhat by making very large images but this is costly and will break down at high zoom levels in any case.

Is it possible to do what I want either via the Leaflet API or some other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "blurrying" of the image is not due to Leaflet, it's due to your web browser. When an image, any image, is loaded in a webpage *at a size different than the image's  pixel dimensions*, the browser must rescale it, with a scaling algorithm of its choosing.

*Some* browsers let web authors tweak this behaviour through the [`image-rendering` CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering).

You can apply CSS rules to *all* `L.ImageOverlay`s with something like:

```
.leaflet-layer-image {
   image-rendering: crisp-edges
}
```

As of Leaflet 1.0.2, it is not yet possible to specify CSS classes for specific `ImageOverlay`s.

**Beware of varying browser support**. Support for the `image-rendering` CSS rule varies **wildly** between different web browsers.

---

Solutions like the one described in the question [Using nearest-neighbor with CSS zoom on canvas (and img)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028864/using-nearest-neighbor-with-css-zoom-on-canvas-and-img) are not really applicable here, as Leaflet relies heavily on CSS transforms to set the image size. If you were to use a `<canvas>`-based technique, it would either break or need to be redrawn at each zoom level change.

(P.S.: If you can find a good *reliable* cross-browser way to force the downsizing/upsizing algorithm in all major browsers, please make a pull request so that Leaflet can benefit from that)

Comment: Thank you @IvanSanchez, I did stumble across `image-rendering`, will look into your suggestions closer.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking into this, I found a `CSS` to achieve desired behavious in [Leaflet's github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5883#issue-269071844), that seem to work in most browsers (the accepted answer did not work for me):

```
/* Leaflet crispness override */
.leaflet-container .leaflet-overlay-pane svg,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-marker-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-shadow-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile-pane img,
.leaflet-container img.leaflet-image-layer {
  max-width: none !important;
  /* Preserve crisp pixels with scaled up images */
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /* Legal fallback */
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox        */
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera          */
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Safari         */
  image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         /* CSS3 Proposed  */
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;               /* CSS4 Proposed  */
  image-rendering: pixelated;                 /* CSS4 Proposed  */
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE8+           */
}
```